# Rails: Ensure only one boolean field is set to true at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a model that has fields of `name:string`, `default:boolean`. I want the `true` value to be unique so that only one item in the database can be set to true at once. How do I set my update and new actions in my controller to set all the rest of the values of items to `false`?

Let's say I have the following setup in my database

```
name:string | default:boolean |  
Item1       | true            |  
Item2       | false           |  
Item3       | false           |
```

If I change `Item2` default value to true, I want it to loop through all items and set the rest of them to `false`, so only one is `true` at once, so it looks like this.

```
name:string | default:boolean |  
Item1       | false           |  
Item2       | true            |  
Item3       | false           |
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This code is stolen from previous answer and slightly simplified:

```
def falsify_all_others
  Item.where('id != ?', self.id).update_all("default = 'false'")
end
```

You can use this method in before_save callback in your model.

Actually, it is better to "falsify" only records which values are 'true', like this:

```
Item.where('id != ? and default', self.id).update_all("default = 'false'")
```

UPDATE: to keep code DRY, use `self.class` instead of `Item`:

```
self.class.where('id != ? and default', self.id).update_all("default = 'false'")
```

Comment: Much better to use standard sql for the id compare `'id <> ?'`. Make sure you only fire off the update_all if the current value of default is true too.

Comment: I use after_save just in case the save failed.

Comment: @MarianoCavallo http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all - in short, update_all does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's good to check if the one you save is true before you falsify others. Otherwise you falsify everyone when you save a record that isn't active.

```
def falsify_all_others
    if self.default
        self.class.where('id != ? and default', self.id).update_all("default = 'false'")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In your controller code you could do something like this....  please note you're probably taking Item2 as a param[...] so you can interchange that below

```
@items_to_be_falsified = Item.where('id != ?', Item2.id)

@items_to_be_falsified.each do |item|
  item.default = false
  item.save
end
```

Please note when you get this working, its good practice to move this into the model, make it into a function and call it like `Item2.falsify_all_others` like below

```
def falsify_all_others
  Item.where('id != ?', self.id).each do |item|
    item.default = false
    item.save
  end
end
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This works perfect thanks, and now I have learned how to do anything like this in the future.

Comment: You'd better use `update_all` here. This code may be performing thousands of queries.

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend falsifying all your records then making them true.

```
add_column :users, :name ,:boolean, default: false
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay there is a few more things you will need.

Don't use the field name default, its usually reserved for the database.
Saving a record with a default as false will set all records to false, this isnt what you want. check to see if we are setting this record to true and the falseify.

```
  before_save :falsify_all_others
  def falsify_all_others
    if is_default
      self.class.where('id != ?', self.id).where('is_default').update_all(:is_default => false)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I ran into this. I kept wondering why my falsify_all was over rewriting the new default. You are saying using the column name default causes problems like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're coming here in a more recent time and are using Rails 6, this should be covered on the database level as well as the model level:

**db level:**

```
add_index :items, :default, unique: true, where: '(default IS TRUE)'
```

**model level:**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  scope :default, -> { where(default: true) }
  
  validates :default, uniqueness: { conditions: -> { default } }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want this to work for creating and updating (rails v4)
make note of this tidbit from [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object)

> after_save runs both on create and update, but always after the more
>   specific callbacks after_create and after_update, no matter the order
>   in which the macro calls were executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :ensure_single_default, if: :is_default?

  private

  def ensure_single_default
    self.class.update_all(is_default: false)
  end
end
```

You don't need to check the id because this callback happens before the truthy one is saved.

Comment: I feel like this might not work well, because it will update before the save, and there's no rolling back the changes to the other records if the save doesn't complete. It does happen after validation, so it's probably fine though.

Comment: I have this working in the wild / covered with specs

Answer (score 1):

More ActiveRecord, less raw SQL decision

```
after_commit :reset_default, if: :default?

private

def reset_default
  self.class.where.not(id: id).where(default: true).update_all(default: false)
end
```

Comment: I'm down with this because it happens after_commit, so you know everything has settled.