# Has_one association confusion, I want it reversed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I'm pretty new to rails and lately I found that I understood activerecords *has_one* association contrary to how it actually works. Refering to the example from [rubyonrails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one) I imagined that it is the *supplier* that should hold its *account_id*, since I see no point in forcing every account to hold its supplier.

Because I don't really understand why, or simply don't agree with the object maintaining it's foreign keys in other objects, I don't know what would be the correct rails solution for my simple problem:
I have two objects - *document*, and *draft*. Every document has many drafts, and one of them is marked as the current draft. I imagined the table layout to be something like this:

```
table document
    id
    current_draft_id
table draft
    id
    document_id
    text
```

What I'm looking for here is something like a *has_one* association, but reversed, so that the document would held and maintain the *current_draft_id*. Using *belongs_to* is not an option because of its different behaviour. For example I'd like *document.current_draft = new_draft* to update the foreign_key correctly.

How to approach this in rails?

-- *update 1*

To clarify my problem, please assume that the draft being *current* won't have nothing to do with *created_at* and *updated_at* fields, so scopes won't do.

Adding a *current* field to the *drafts* table would be a weird move from the table design point of view. I'm also planning to add information about the *published draft* to the *document* object, and multiplying such informations in *drafts* tableseems to be an odd step.

I like Amesee's idea, but still I have some inner resistances, similar to adding the *current*  column to the *drafts* table.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that `Draft` is a `Document` so it may make more sense to manage these classes with single table inheritance. You can tell that a draft is a "current draft" by its type.

```
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :documents do |t|
      t.string :type
      # ...

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And the models.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end

class Draft < Document
  # ...
end

class CurrentDraft < Draft
  # ...
end
```

Later on, when a draft isn't "current" anymore, update its type by changing its `type` attribute to "Draft" or "Document." I think this is a better solution than constantly checking a boolean or date attribute on the object and asking about its state everywhere in the application.

Comment: You have a valid point there, I'll consider it. But I still think that from the table layout point of view my scheme would end up easier to maintain.

Comment: And on the second thought what if I'd like the drafts share the same fields like title from the document object?

Comment: All these classes shared the same underlying table so they already share the same set of attributes (technically they all have the same attribute accessor methods). The only difference is the underlying type of object that is instantiated according to the value of `type`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you enforce which draft is the "current" draft? Would it be the most recently created one? The last one edited? I would have the current draft be a logically calculated facet of the draft table and find it with scopes, rather than force a fixed ID that may not always match the logic.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drafts

  def current_draft
    self.drafts.ordered.first
  end
end

class Draft < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document

  scope :all
  scope :ordered, order_by(:updated_at)
end
```

Alternatively, add a `:current, :boolean, :default => false` field to the drafts table and have there be only one child with current being true. (A good explanation of the logic for this method can be found here: [Rails 3 app model how ensure only one boolean field set to true at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134898/rails-3-app-model-how-ensure-only-one-boolean-field-set-to-true-at-a-time))

If you *really* want to have a fixed child ID in the parent, then you need a `:belongs_to` with a defined foreign key:

documents table:

```
id
current_draft_id
```

Model:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drafts
  belongs_to :current_draft, :class_name => 'Draft', :foreign_key => 'current_draft_id'
end
```

Controller code somewhere:

```
@document.current_draft = @draft
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, please see the *update 1* to my question. I also talked about the *belongs\_to* association differing from what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: My final suggestion matches what you want to do precisely, you add the field as in your original post, you call it via `.current_draft` , I don't see why it wont work for you? Edit: I've clarified it a bit.

Comment: Look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and find the _Is it a belongs\_to or has\_one association?_ paragraph. _belongs\_to_ association assumes that in our example it would be the _draft_ object that would be responsible for maintaining its key in *document* object. In consequence `@document.current_draft = @draft` will not update the document object.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something in my writing, you can't use a has_one because you already has_many and you want the ID in the parent table, you need a belongs to so that the document can belong to a single draft while having many drafts. You just need to define which field within the document table contains the ID of the owning draft, and a name for the relationship. I've tested this, it works.

Comment: I pointed out that _belongs\_to_ has a different semantics from what I'm trying to achieve. I want the _document_ object to be the master of the _current\_draft\_id_, not the _draft_. Using this relation in such way looks like a dirty hack, since methods generated by both associations differ in some details. And I don't want to ask for trouble.

Comment: The reverse of a has_one is a belongs_to, it's not a dirty hack at all, it works exactly as you want it to, ignore what you think the documentation is telling you and give it a go, it works! The rails way of doing what you want is to have the current draft be a facet in the draft model, or some form of inheritance, but you've rejected that out of hand, so I have included a suggestion that exactly matches what you want to do in the way you want to do it, and you're rejecting that out of hand too, without even testing it. You seem to be unhelpable. Good luck with your project.