# Rails: getting all records except currently created one in after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm having an issue looping over all records except the newly created one in `after_create`.

My models:

Customer - `has_many :registries`

Registry - `belongs_to :customer`

Basically my registry model has a field called "active" and only 1 registry can be active at a time. The default value of the "active" field is `true`.

I have an after_create method on the registry model that is looping over all registries owned by the customer except the newly created one and setting "active" to `false`.

First off, there very well may be a better way to do this.

But anyway, my `after_create` within `registry.rb` looks something like this:

```
def deactivate_other_registries 
  customer.registries.where.not(id: id).each do |r|
    r.active = false
    r.save!
  end
end
```

This seems to work on and off, and I think it may be due to race conditions.

Then I tried changing `after_create` to `after_save` and turning it into:

```
def deactivate_other_registries 
  if new_record?
    customer.registries.where.not(id: id).each do |r|
      r.active = false
      r.save!
    end
  end
end
```

This didn't seem to solve my issues either.

I'm not sure how to achieve what I need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: Ensure only one boolean field is set to true at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134898/rails-ensure-only-one-boolean-field-is-set-to-true-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have reason to need a record of the timestamp when the other registries I would suggest using update_all, without running through the lifecycle events on save.  It will cut down on your race conditions.

```
after_create :deactivate_other_registries

def deactivate_other_registries
  self.customer.registries.where.not(id: self.id)&.update_all(active: false)
end
```

Comment: You don't need `self` and `&` here

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the callback to:

```
after_commit :deactivate_other_registries, on: :create
```

And then:

```
def deactivate_other_registries
 customer.registries.where.not(id: self.id).update_all(active: false)
end
```

And this seemed to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since only 1 registry can be active at a time, it looks like you need `after_commit` not only `on: :create`, but also `on: :update` (let's assume you will activate some registry manually)

Rails 6 introduced [`after_save_commit`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_save_commit) for this purpose

Let's assume you need to create new non-active registry, in this case, active registry will be deactivated, it is not good behaviour

Finally I suggest such code:

```rb
after_save_commit, if: :active?

private

def deactivate_other_registries
  customer.registries.where.not(id: id).update_all(active: false)
end
```